# Produce a value based on aggregated rows where I want to CASE on multiple values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of the following form:

```
| PersonId | Eats              |
|----------|-------------------|
| 1        | Meat              |
| 1        | Animal Byproducts |
| 1        | Vegetables        |
| 2        | Animal Byproducts |
| 2        | Vegetables        |
| 3        | Vegetables        |
```

And I want to turn it into a table like:

```
| PersonId | DietaryPreference  |
|----------|--------------------|
| 1        | Omnivore           |
| 2        | Vegetarian         |
| 3        | Vegan              |
```

My initial thought is do to something like

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        PersonId, 
        STRING_AGG (Eats,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Eats ASC) AS EatsConcat
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY PersonId
)
SELECT 
    PersonId,
    CASE EatsConcat
        WHEN 'Animal Byproducts,Meat,Vegetables' THEN 'Omnivore' 
        WHEN 'Animal Byproducts,Vegetables'      THEN 'Vegetarian'
        WHEN 'Vegetables'                        THEN 'Vegan'
    END AS DietaryPreference
FROM cte
```

but this seems like a messy way of doing it since there's no real reason to use string aggregration when what I'm really doing is set comparison. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Creating a mapping table comes to mind.  What's the (programmatic) logic that determines which Dietary Preference someone fits into?  For example, what can programmatically separate someone as Omnivore and Vegetarian?  Does your whole problem fit within this or is this a trimmed down example?

Comment: @squillman Omnivore = must have exactly ('Meat', 'Animal Byproducts', 'Vegetables'); Vegetarian = must have exactly ('Animal Byproducts', 'Vegetables'); Vegan = must have exactly ('Vegetables'). My problem does map to this, with a few more cases, but as long as we have exact group matching, it'll solve my problem.

Comment: What about someone that only east meat?

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* that simply someone that eats meat, regardless of what others they might not, is an Omnivore, and someone that eats Animal Byproducts (but not meat) is a Vegetarian, then you could do something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT V.PersonID,
           COUNT(CASE V.Eats WHEN 'Meat' THEN 1 END) AS Meat,
           COUNT(CASE V.Eats WHEN 'AnimalByproducts' THEN 1 END) AS AnimalByproducts,
           COUNT(CASE V.Eats WHEN 'Vegetables' THEN 1 END) AS Vegetables
    FROM (VALUES(1,'Meat'),
                (1,'AnimalByproducts'),
                (1,'Vegetables'),
                (2,'AnimalByproducts'),
                (2,'Vegetables'),
                (3,'Vegetables'))V(PersonID,Eats)
     GROUP BY V.PersonID)
SELECT C.PersonID,
       CASE WHEN C.Meat > 0 THEN 'Omnivore'
            WHEN AnimalByproducts > 0 THEN 'Vegetarian' 
            WHEN Vegetables > 0 THEN 'Vegan'
            ELSE 'Very hungry'
       END
FROM CTE C;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation to process the hierarchy of values:

```
select personid,
       coalesce(max(case when eats in ('Meat') then 'Omnivore' end),
                max(case when eats in ('Animal Byproducts') then 'Vegetarian' end),
                max(case when etas in ('Vegetables') then 'Vegan' end)
               ) as dietarypreference
from mytable
group by personid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use just aggregation and no `CASE`.

The below prefixes each of the dietary preferences with a digit, so that the order of the selection hierarchy is also the lexicographic order and it can be used with `MAX`, and then finds the `MAX` and strips the digit off in the final `SELECT`

```
SELECT m.PersonId,
       SUBSTRING(MAX(V.DietaryPreference), 2, 8000) AS DietaryPreference
FROM   MyTable m
       JOIN (VALUES ('Meat','3Omnivore'),
                    ('AnimalByproducts','2Vegetarian'),
                    ('Vegetables', '1Vegan')) V(Eats, DietaryPreference)
         ON V.Eats = M.Eats
GROUP  BY m.PersonId
```